# Why value to a setter is assigned with = and not through ( )

Tags: flutter, dart, getter-setter

Countdown Provider code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CountdownProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _counter;
  bool _showText = true;

  int get getCounter => _counter;

  set setCounter(int value) {
    _counter = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool get getShowText => _showText;

  set setShowText(bool value) {
    _showText = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Countdown Screen code :

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:timer_app/countdown_provider.dart';

class CountdownScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController timerValue = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: theme.canvasColor,
        elevation: 0,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      body: Consumer<CountdownProvider>(
        builder: (context, timerProvider, child) {
          int counter = timerProvider.getCounter;
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "How many seconds",
                      style: theme.textTheme.headline5,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 80,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: timerValue,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: [
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3),
                        ],
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: theme.textTheme.subtitle1,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                        onEditingComplete: () {
                          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                          timerProvider.setCounter = int.parse(timerValue.text);
                          print('counter --- ${timerProvider.getCounter}');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 90,
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 200,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueGrey),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                            child: timerProvider.getShowText
                                ? Text(
                                    "Let's Go",
                                    key: UniqueKey(),
                                    style: theme.textTheme.headline4,
                                  )
                                : Text(
                                    "$counter",
                                    key: UniqueKey(),
                                    style: theme.textTheme.headline1
                                        .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                                  ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        Timer.run(() {
                          Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
                            timerProvider.setShowText(false); //-------------- this line is throwing error
                            if (counter == -1) {
                              timer.cancel();
                            } else {
                              timerProvider.setCounter = counter--;
                            }
                          });
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Tap on circle to start countdown",
                      style: theme.textTheme.subtitle1,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 90,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.replay_sharp,
                    size: 32,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    timerValue.clear();
                    timerProvider.setShowText = true;
                    timerProvider.setCounter = null;
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using android studio and I generated getter and setter through its options, not manually. I thought, setter will take value as an argument within brackets, as I looked at its syntax, however it gives this error if I try to use any of the setter in the format pointed in code.

Error: The method 'setShowText' isn't defined for the type 'CountdownProvider'

My fellow dev said to change syntax like this:

`timerProvider.setShowText = false;` and it works!

His explanation is its only because of 'set' keyword. With 'Set' keyword, setter will take only single value, and any framework/language will work behind the scenes in such a way, that it will take value only through equals to. Not as I thought like we pass a value as an argument through () to a function.

I was not fully convinced with his answer. I searched about Getters/Setters and saw that yes in every tutorial or example that exists on the internet, they have used = to assign value, but why.

Answer (score 1):

The entire point of the `get` and `set` keywords is to make getters and setters syntactically identical to member variable access and assignment respectively.  Otherwise the keywords wouldn't be necessary at all and they could be ordinary functions:

```dart
int getCounter() => _counter;

void setCounter(int value) {
  _counter = value;
  notifyListeners();
}

bool getShowText() => _showText;

void setShowText(bool value) {
  _showText = value;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

which is what you'd do in most other programming languages that don't have specific language support for getters and setters.

Dart's approach of allowing getters/setters to look like member variables provides API flexibility: if you have a class that starts off with simple member variables but later want to add logic when accessing or assigning member variables, you won't need to change the API.

Also see the [Getters and setters](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#getters-and-setters) section of the Dart Language Tour.

Note that your usage of getters and setters is not idiomatic.  You shouldn't *name* a getter with `get...` and a setter with `set...`; that's redundant.  You'd instead want them to be:

```dart
int get counter => _counter;

set counter(int value) {
  _counter = value;
  notifyListeners();
}

bool get showText => _showText;

set showText(bool value) {
  _showText = value;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

so that setting would be done with, say, `timerProvider.showText = false;`.